# GoogleChart Maps [visualization] error while joining/displaying 2 datasets

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, geomap

My Dataset 1 is like this-

```
var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data1.addColumn('string','Country');
            data1.addColumn('string','Data1');
            for(var j=0;j<enterpriseArray.length;j++){
                data1.addRows([[enterpriseArray[j], suspiciousCountArray[j]]]);
            }
```

And Dataset 2 is pretty similar-

```
var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data2.addColumn('string','Country');
            data2.addColumn('string','Data2');
            for(var k=0;k<enterpriseArray.length;k++){
                data2.addRows([[enterpriseArray[k], malicousCountArray[k]]]);
            }
```

And finally this-

```
var jointData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('some-div'));
chart.draw(jointData, options);
```

I get this error, not on the Console, but on the exact place where my chart is supposed to be displayed.

```
Error- Incompatible data table: Error: Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 2 columns)
```

P.S.- If I use my dataset something like this (with hard-coded data, not dynamic)-

```
var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Country', 'Activity'],
                ['Germany', 100],
                ['United States', 200],
                ['India', 350],
            ]);
var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Country', 'Activity'],
                ['Germany', 200],
                ['United States', 300],
                ['India', 50],
            ]);
```

Then the chart/map is displayed correctly without any errors.

Comment: why is `Data1` and `Data2` type as `string`? Shouldn't it be `number`. See if this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4zk15abz/2/) helps you.

Comment: Data1, Data2 contain mostly zeros, so I get this if i set both to number and not string- Error: Type mismatch. Value 0 does not match type number in column index 1

Comment: Hey I solved it, will post that an answer. Your solution was on point though, just that the data that i was getting was in the form of a string and I had to cast it to integer.

Comment: Good to know .!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#data-format) for [GeoChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart),
the data can be in one of three formats, according to the type of chart you want to display...

**1) Regions mode**

the data table should have at least one `'string'` column for location,
and an optional `'number'` column for color

**2) Markers mode**

the data table should have at least one `'string'` column for location,
OR two `'number'` columns for latitude & longitude respectively,
followed by an optional `'number'` column for marker color,
and another `'number'` columns for marker size

**3) Text mode**

the data table should have at least one `'string'` column for location,
and an optional `'number'` column for size of the text

---

none of the formats allow for more than one `'string'` column,
which is why you receive the following error...
`Table contains more columns than expected`

the error you receive when switching those columns to `'number'`,
is because the numbers you are loading are in `'string'` format

use `parseFloat` or `parseInt`...

```
data1.addRows([[enterpriseArray[j], parseFloat(suspiciousCountArray[j])]]);
```

Comment: hope this helps, keep in mind, the only format that allows for two numeric column is markers mode (color and size)...

Comment: Good knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I needed to cast string to an integer (from the dynamic data that I wanted to display; used parseInt for this), and then changed the type for Data1 and Data2 to 'number' as **Pirate X** pointed out in his comment.